# .DLL comments included in the .XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, dll

I have a .DLL that i include in my Visual Studio 2008 project.  The .DLL came with a .XML file that has all the comments for the properties and functions.

How do i make it so that VS loads up these comments as Intellisense, so that i have a definition for the functions?

-------------UPDATE---------------------
The files are placed under the same folder:

FTD2XX_NET.XML
FTD2XX_NET.DLL

When i look into Object browser, i do see the comments.  I just don't see them in the intellisense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was my understanding that as long as the XML file was in the same directory as the referenced DLL then the comments would automatically be shown in the intellisense tooltips.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case.
The .DLL in question is FTD2XX_NET.dll from FTDI

Answer (score 6):

The DLL and XML must exist together in the same location referenced by Visual Studio and they must have the same name.

Comment: In addition, it appears that the .XML file must exist with the .DLL *when* the .DLL is referenced into a project. I had referenced a .DLL without the .XML file present and then later added an appropriate .XML file next to the .DLL. Visual Studio 2010's intellisense refused to recognize the .XML despite rebuilds, load/unload solution, etc. What finally worked was to remove the .DLL reference from the project and then re-reference it (this time with the .XML file there).

Comment: I noticed that sometime it is necessary to reopen VS (2015) in order to have intellisense being refreshed with the xml doc one has just added (reloading projects in a solution is not enough).

Comment: having the same name is what stumped me. thanks. still an issue 8 years later. you think they would rename it for you